# RequiredFieldValidator for a dropdown list populated by an SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Morning All,

I have a dropdown list that is populated by an SQLSataSource.  I wish to make this dropdown list a required field and need to add add a default item like -Please Select- at the top of this list to prompt the user to make a selection.

Here is my code...

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwner" runat="server" DataSourceID="OwnersList" 
       DataTextField="UserFullName" DataValueField="UserFullName" Height="24px" 
       Width="125px">
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOwner"
       ControlToValidate="ddOwner" 
       ErrorMessage="Please assign an Owner"
       Text="*" 
       runat="server" Display="None"/>
```

Can i add some code into the 'Initial value' item to set the -Please select- default item?

Regards Betty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an unbound item:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwner" runat="server" DataSourceID="OwnersList" 
       DataTextField="UserFullName" DataValueField="UserFullName" Height="24px" 
       AppendDataBoundItems="true"
       Width="125px">
     <asp:ListItem Text="-Please Select-" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with after your `DataBind Method`

```
...

ddOwner.DataBind();
ddOwner.Items.Add("Please select- default item?");
```